# Run multiple socket.io-clients in one node.js instance

Tags: node.js

I want to run stress tests using node.js, socket.io, and socket.io-client.

I want to get the network bandwidth, processor/memory use, etc.

I have a node.js socket.io server on amazon, size XLARGE.

Now I want to run multiple socket.io-clients in other amazon servers, and connect them to my server.

I was running it in different processes, but one node.js process takes 15MB memory. I want to test 100k socket.io connections simultaneously, so this is not an option.

My question is: Can I run, for example, 60k different socket.io-clients in one node.js instance?

This is my client code:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://someAddress:3000');
  socket.on('connect', function(){      
  socket.on('news', function(data){ 
});
socket.emit('event', { data: "Connection test." });
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to pass `forceNew` option:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://someAddress:3000', {
  forceNew: true
});
```

And then initialize your sockets in a loop.

Here is a full test example:

**server.js:**

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    socket.emit('news', {
      message: i++
    });
  }, 1000);
});
io.listen(3000);
```

**client,js:**

```
function testOne() {
  var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://127.0.0.1:3000', {forceNew: true});
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.on('news', function(data){
      console.log(data.message);
    });
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  testOne();
}
```

For testing purpose I've made client to output incrementing number for five times each second.

Comment: As far as my tests are correct, socket.io generates a new socket id when reconnecting in command line mode. So no, they're not persistent

Comment: Well i need persistents for tests. But when I'm connecting without any emiting, server showing 1k sockets connected, if they were not presistents it should drop to 0 without emiting then?

Comment: I guess I misundertood you. Correct me if I got you wrong. I meant that they're not persistent because when network connection is gone and then appear again, old sockets are being removed and new ones are created. But if network is OK, they are still connected even if you're not emitting to them

Comment: Ah ok! I just thought that "not presistent" means, that they are handshaking in every emit.

Comment: For a bit of clarity: forceNew is not dropping previous connections if that was what you were worried about. It is making a new connection every time you connect but that connection will change details if it becomes disconnected somehow. So old connections are not removed, but none of these connections are permanent.

Comment: I figured out how exactly socket.io behaves in this case: if network connection is lost and after, say, 30 sec appears again, server will get all client's messages sent in disconnection period, and vice versa. But, if disconnection period lasts more than about 1.5 min (due to my tests), server breaks old connections and establishes new ones (with new socket IDs) when network appears. I believe this disconnection period should be configurable, but right now socket.io website, as well as Github wiki page, is under reconstruction. It would be educating to read about it in the official docs.

Comment: @Curious I have used net sockets library, and have made a class, i initialize two objects with different IP's and same PORT number, when i get connect with both objects, both show the IP of last connected object, even i have used this.Socket = new require( 'net' ).Socket(); in the constructor :(

Comment: @shzyincu node.js `net` module is not connected with `socket.io` library, it's a different thing. You can post a new question, with code samples, so it would be easier to help

Comment: @Curious :) I have finished OOP based class, also i have debugged my issue thanks alot :)